# Element not repainted until mouse movement onto or off element in Webkit

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

I have an element containing 3D-transformed elements. In webkit, the content of the parent element are not correctly repainted until I mouse over or off the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

to the parent element solved the repainting/reflow issue.